# web application reset

Tags: asp.net

i have two .net web application and they ara running on different domain same machine.

if i edit one's of them web.config file.
which applications will be reset?both or only one?

CASE 1:A's web.config edited.

Application A : xxx.yyy.com
Application B : zzz.yyy.com

CASE 2:A's web.config edited.

Application A : www.yyy.com/ApplicationA/
Application B : www.yyy.com/ApplicationB/

Comment: Do they point to the same codebase(ie: both use the same web.config)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one. Each application instance within IIS does not affect any other application as far as I'm aware.

I.e.

```
IIS               // Resetting IIS will affect Application1 and Application2
...Application1
......Web.Config  // Modifying this will not affect Application2
...Application2
......Web.Config
```

**EDIT:**

To summarise. If each application is in a separate directory which are referenced as different applications by IIS, then modifying the codebase of one application will not affect the other. However, if two applications are setup that share the same directory/files, then changing those files (including the web.config) will cause both applications to reset.

I.e.

Assuming both the following share the same directory on the server and you modify the web.config in that directory:

> Application A : xxx.yyy.com
>   Application A :
>   www.yyy.com/ApplicationA/

Then Application B will not be reset.

But modifiying either of:

> Application B : zzz.yyy.com
>   Application B :
>   www.yyy.com/ApplicationB/

Will cause Application B to reset.

Comment: i added cases for my probabilities.please take a look

Comment: My answer still applies. Editing one of the Web.Config files will NOT affect the other one. It doesn't matter whether it's in a sub directory or subdomain, as long as they are setup as separate applications in IIS.

Comment: for web.config file ok,so updating for a dll file same?

Comment: Modifying any file within the application's individual directory WILL NOT affect any other application.

Comment: How can they share the same codebase if they're in separate directories?

Comment: you said "referenced as different applications by IIS" what do you mean?

Comment: As in... setup as separate applications/virtual directories in Internet Information Services.

Answer (score 0):

If the configured applications use the same codebase(ie:same web.config) then yes, otherwise no.

EDIT:
Any application(virtual, root..etc) that points to the same web.config on the same IIS server, will be affected.

Comment: i added cases for my probabilities.please take a look